# Inherited pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, pure-virtual

Let's imagine the following situation: `A` is an abstract class defining a pure virtual function `void f()`; `B` is a class that implements a function `void f()`; `C` inherits from both `A` and `B`:

```
struct A                     
{                            
    void virtual f() =0;     
};                           

struct B                     
{                            
    virtual void f() { }     
};                           

struct C : public A, public B
{                            
};
```

The question could be: Is `C` an abstract class? The requirements deriving from `A` being abstract are that the subclass implements the virtual function `void f()`. `C` does not implement it directly, but inherits it from `B`.

I can already answer this question: Yes, `C` is an abstract class. If you try to instantiate an object of type `C` you'll get a compilation error. So the actual question is: Why is `C` an abstract class?

I suppose that the fact that `A::f` and `B::f` have the same name and signature is not enough to draw a correspondence between these functions so to say that `B::f` implements `A::f`. From a technical point of view I can see that these functions "reside" in different parts of the object of type `C` (though I'm not really sure that my understanding is complete).  But from a conceptual point of view I could easily imagine a situation where a class `C` wants to be an implementation of the abstract class `A` and, in order to implement the pure virtual function `f`, it uses the implementation of one of its parent classes. The solution is probably to do:

```
struct C : public A, public B
{
    virtual void f() { B::f(); }
};
```

, which worked in my experiment. But is this trick necessary?

**EDIT:**

Further question: Is the order in which `C` inherits from `A` and `B` relevant? Would it change something if I wrote the following?

```
struct C : public B, public A
{
};
```

The answer (again, I test my codes, then I try to ask non-trivial questions) is no, it does not change anything. But in this case (correct me if I'm wrong), `C::f`, if implemented, would override `B::f`, not `A::f`. Since `A::f` would not be accessible using a `C` object does it make sense to request that it is implemented?

Comment: Remove the "trick" and See if `C instance;` compiles to see if it was necessary.

Comment: I tried with and without the "trick". It is necessary, otherwise `C` is considered abstract. The "trick" is to use `B::f` as an implementation for the needed virtual function. All you need in facts is an implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

`C` also inherits from `B` doesn't make a bit of difference when it considers the functions inherited from `A`. So, when it compiler sees that `C` doesn't override pure virtual from `A`, it makes it an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

> The requirements deriving from A being abstract are that the subclass implements the virtual function

Not quite. The requirement is that the subclass *overrides* the pure virtual function, with a non-pure function. A function in one base class doesn't override one in another base class; `C` itself must declare an override to be non-abstract.

> But is this trick necessary?

Yes. You have to override the function in a class derived from `A`; in this case, that means `C`.

> Is the order in which `C` inherits from `A` and `B` relevant?

No, the declaration order makes little difference. The override must be declared in a class derived from `A`.

> But in this case (correct me if I'm wrong), `C::f`, if implemented, would override `B::f`, not `A::f`.

It would override both, regardless of the declaration order of the base classes.

> Since `A::f` would not be accessible using a `C` object does it make sense to request that it is implemented?

Both are still accessible (although the name will need to be qualified since an unqualified `f` is ambiguous). The pure function still needs to be overridden to make the derived class non-abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answers haven't been updated for your new questions, here are the answers to them.

> But in this case (correct me if I'm wrong), C::f, if implemented, would override B::f, not A::f.

You're half wrong. Both `A::f` and `B::f` are overridden by `C::f` regardless of the order of inheritance.

> Since A::f would not be accessible using a C object does it make sense to request that it is implemented?

But `A::f` **is** accessible using a `C` object. Consider this, rather typical use of inheritance:

```
void call_f(A& a) {
    a.f();
}
int main() {
    C c;
    call_f(c);
}
```

If `C` doesn't override `A::f`, then this couldn't possibly work. It makes sense that a concrete subclass of `A` must implement `A::f`.